# How to get Authenticated with spring security rest plugin in Grails

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.4

I'm using Grails version 2.4.3 . I am creating an application that supports RESTful APIs. Since  access to these APIs should be authenticated , I tried out the Spring Security REST plugin. I checked out [this example](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/restful-grails-springsecurity-greach2014) and what I could understand is , the `/api/login` controller is the authentication point which receives the user credentials in JSON format and after successful authentication it provides the acces token as response. I tried sending a POST request to `/api/login/` with valid JSON data using the [POSTMAN Rest Client](http://www.getpostman.com/). But it gives me the following error.

```
401 Unauthorized , Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.
```

I also tried using IntellijIDEA's REST Client but doesn't work.
Then i tried by sending AJAX Request to `/api/login/` with valid JSON data
, but getting 401 on console. What is the problem here?  Is this the correct login end point? How can i get authenticated using JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
        url: " http://localhost:8080/AppName/api/login",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({"username":"yourusername" , "password":"yourpassword"}),
        contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);


        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    })  });
```

Comment: To sent JSON using POSTMAN , choose the `raw` tab -> select JSON and paste your json data in the textarea

Comment: i am gettin similar issues..does my request is correct?                     POST /GhumVer3/api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 02c8faa5-d1a9-9192-b26a-cd98186551f6

{"username":"test" , "password":"test123"}

Comment: What did you try and how? Please explain.. or add some code

Comment: hey i  have added code here :https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/issues/181#issuecomment-78252753

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for authentication,I am sending user id and password in request header you can try as you wish :-
inject following services:-

```
def springSecurityService
def authenticationManager
```

and use following code

```
def login = {
            final String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            if (authorization != null && authorization.startsWith("Basic")) {
                boolean authResult = authenticateUser(authorization)
                if (authResult) {
                    render response.status
                } else {
                    render authFailed(response)
                }

            } else {
                render authFailed(response)
            }
        }
   protected boolean authenticateUser(String authorization) {
        // Authorization: Basic base64credentials
        def base64Credentials = authorization.substring("Basic".length()).trim();
        byte[] credentials = base64Credentials.decodeBase64()
        String actualCredential = new String(credentials)
        // credentials format like username:password
        final String[] values = actualCredential.split(":", 2);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(values[0], values[1]);

        try {
            def authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
            def securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
            def session = request.session;
            session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
        }
        catch (BadCredentialsException exception) {
            return false

        }
        return true

    }

    protected HttpServletResponse authFailedResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setStatus(401)
        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"nmrs_m7VKmomQ2YM3:\"")
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. But where i have to use this code?  Is  `/api/login` a dynamic controller created by the plugin?  Can you please explain how i could use this code?

Comment: Also in the same example , when i tried usin [php curl](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl) , it is working fine and I'm getting the expected response.. Then what's wrong with the JQuery , and REST client requests?

Comment: @Jrd You can use it in your controller inside your method.